# Regex replace in Python picking a specific substring

Tags: python

Here's what I want to happen:

```
input = "asdsad,200200-12964,0009,""TREASURY SETTLEMENT NON-COMPLIANCE ASSESSMENT FOR CPD2020-01-21 USD 589,037.17"" 0.00000000,1.000000"

output = "asdsad,200200-12964,0009,""TREASURY SETTLEMENT NON-COMPLIANCE ASSESSMENT FOR CPD2020-01-21 USD 589.037.17"" 0.00000000,1.000000"
```

How can I change the comma (`,`) to a dot (`.`) between `""...589,037.17...""` in Python using regex.

```
Extra: 589,037.17 => 589.037.17
```

I tried:

```
print(re.sub(r'(?<=\d),', '.', input))
```

But my output was:

```
output = "asdsad,200200-12964.0009,""TREASURY SETTLEMENT NON-COMPLIANCE ASSESSMENT FOR CPD2020-01-21 USD 589.037.17"" 0.00000000,1.000000"
```

Comment: you are getting the output you mentioned above, What is the real output want?

Comment: It's hard to see, but there is a dot changed in the first bit, OP only wants it changed in the price.

Answer (score 0):

First, don't call a variable `input`, because it overwrites the the built-in function `input()`. Also you repeated strings are just one string in Python.

```
i = 'asdsad,200200-12964,0009,TREASURY SETTLEMENT NON-COMPLIANCE ASSESSMENT FOR CPD2020-01-21 USD 589,037.17 0.00000000,1.000000'
```

To solve your specific case, you could match a the country code followed by 3 numbers in the first bit of the price before the comma. That works for this, but probably isn't generic enough for any country code and any price, as look-behinds must be of fixed width.

```
print(re.sub(r'(?<=USD \d{3}),', '.', i))
```

I would use a look-behind for the country code and space, then group the first bit of the number and replace it with a backreference.

```
print(re.sub(r'(?<=[A-Z]{3} )(\d+),', r'\1.', i))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

input = "asdsad,200200-12964,0009,""TREASURY SETTLEMENT NON-COMPLIANCE ASSESSMENT FOR CPD2020-01-21 USD 589,037.17"" 0.00000000,1.000000"
print(input)
print(re.sub(r'USD (\d+),(\d+)', r'USD \1.\2', input))
```

Output:

```
asdsad,200200-12964,0009,TREASURY SETTLEMENT NON-COMPLIANCE ASSESSMENT FOR CPD2020-01-21 USD 589,037.17 0.00000000,1.000000
asdsad,200200-12964,0009,TREASURY SETTLEMENT NON-COMPLIANCE ASSESSMENT FOR CPD2020-01-21 USD 589.037.17 0.00000000,1.000000
```

You can go through this [Search and Replace](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#search-and-replace) and [this](https://pythontesting.net/python/regex-search-replace-examples/) link for documenation on this.